# Bounding sum of quartic deviations from sample mean

Tags: probability, statistics

I came across the following statement in [The Jackknife and Bootstrap, Shao and Tu](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387945156%5D), p. 87:

$$\sum_i(X_i-\bar X)^4\leq16\sum_i(X_i-\mu)^4,$$

where $\bar X$ and $\mu$ are the sample mean and expected value of the $X_i$, respectively.

Even without the term 16, the statement is well-known (for any $a$, not only $\mu$ when we replace 4 by 2.

My hunch is that the proof uses Pascal's triangle, as there are 16 terms in the l.h.s. when adding and subtracting $\mu$ and multiplying out:

$$\sum_i(X_i-\bar X)^4=\sum_i(X_i-\mu)^4+4(X_i-\mu)^3(\mu-\bar X)+4(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\bar X)^3+6(X_i-\mu)^2(\mu-\bar X)^2+(\mu-\bar X)^4$$

My attempts at bounding the terms on the r.h.s. (other than the first one, which is already in the "right" format), including Hölder's inequality, however have not led anywhere useful.

Comment: I had cross-posted this question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531457/bounding-sum-of-quartic-deviations-from-sample-mean/544478#544478 after a few days, where you can now find a proof.